# LightDM screen lock in awesome-wm unlocks by itself

Tags: awesome, screen-lock, lightdm

I use [LightDM](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/) with [awesome-wm](https://awesomewm.org/).

To lock screen I use command `dm-tool lock`. Most of the time it works fine but if after issuing the session lock command I switch to another tty and then go back, session unlocks by itself. `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` is set to all defaults. How can I fix this behavior?

---

- Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26)
- awesome v4.0
- lightdm 1.18.3-1

**EDIT**

Output of the `systemctl status lightdm.service` command after a couple of locks

```
CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
           ├─ 931 /usr/sbin/lightdm
           ├─ 941 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
           ├─1754 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp vt8 -novtswitch
           ├─1794 lightdm --session-child 15 24
           ├─2137 lightdm --session-child 27 30
           ├─2192 lightdm --session-child 31 34
           ├─2224 lightdm --session-child 35 38
           └─2304 lightdm --session-child 15 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a solution [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=887773). `light-locker` needs to be running for `dm-tool lock` to work correctly.